# sql oracle Old Join Syntax vs. New

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax

I ask if any one can help me to write my query below use modern join syntax sql oracle :

```
 SELECT /*+ USE_NL_WITH_INDEX(D) */ N.MARCHE,N.NLBIX,D.NUORD,D.NUCON, 0 NUBI2, N.COINF, D.COINL, D.COINA, D.COINV, N.COINN, D.COINC, D.NUCPT, D.COINI, N.COINK, N.CNACT, N.NUCAR
    FROM VBANET N, VBADET D
    WHERE N.MARCHE IN ('DDL')
    AND D.MARCHE(+)= N.MARCHE
    AND D.NUBIX(+)= N.NUBIX AND N.CTFNE NOT IN ('T','R') 
    AND
    D.CTFRE(+) != 'R' AND (N.NLBIX IN (SELECT /*+ UNNEST NO_USE_HASH_AGGREGATION */ DISTINCT FN.NLBIX
    FROM DICCRN FN, RICCRD FD
    WHERE
    FN.MARCHE IN ('OCC') AND
    FD.NLBIX(+)= FN.NLBIX AND
    FD.MARCHE(+)= FN.MARCHE AND
    ( FN.NUSEQ IS NOT NULL OR FD.NUSEQ IS NOT NULL )) );
```

help plz

Answer (score 1):

You appear to want:

```sql
SELECT /*+ USE_NL_WITH_INDEX(D) */
       N.MARCHE,
       N.NLBIX,
       D.NUORD,
       D.NUCON,
       0 NUBI2,
       N.COINF,
       D.COINL,
       D.COINA,
       D.COINV,
       N.COINN,
       D.COINC,
       D.NUCPT,
       D.COINI,
       N.COINK,
       N.CNACT,
       N.NUCAR
FROM   VBANET N
       LEFT OUTER JOIN VBADET D
       ON (   D.MARCHE = N.MARCHE
          AND D.NUBIX  = N.NUBIX
          AND D.CTFRE != 'R'
          )
WHERE  N.MARCHE IN ('DDL')
AND    N.CTFNE NOT IN ('T','R') 
AND    N.NLBIX IN (
         SELECT /*+ UNNEST NO_USE_HASH_AGGREGATION */
                DISTINCT
                FN.NLBIX
         FROM   DICCRN FN
                LEFT OUTER JOIN RICCRD FD
                ON (   FD.NLBIX  = FN.NLBIX
                   AND FD.MARCHE = FN.MARCHE
                   )
         WHERE  FN.MARCHE IN ('OCC')
         AND    ( FN.NUSEQ IS NOT NULL OR FD.NUSEQ IS NOT NULL )
       )
```

*You also probably do not need the `DISTINCT` clause in the sub-query.*

---

You can rewrite the sub-query to:

```sql
SELECT N.MARCHE,
       N.NLBIX,
       D.NUORD,
       D.NUCON,
       0 NUBI2,
       N.COINF,
       D.COINL,
       D.COINA,
       D.COINV,
       N.COINN,
       D.COINC,
       D.NUCPT,
       D.COINI,
       N.COINK,
       N.CNACT,
       N.NUCAR
FROM   VBANET N
       LEFT OUTER JOIN VBADET D
       ON (   D.MARCHE = N.MARCHE
          AND D.NUBIX  = N.NUBIX
          AND D.CTFRE != 'R'
          )
WHERE  N.MARCHE IN ('DDL')
AND    N.CTFNE NOT IN ('T','R') 
AND    EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM   DICCRN FN
         WHERE  FN.MARCHE IN ('OCC')
         AND    N.NLBIX = FN.NLBIX
         AND    ( FN.NUSEQ IS NOT NULL
                OR EXISTS (
                     SELECT 1
                     FROM   RICCRD FD
                     WHERE  FD.NLBIX  = FN.NLBIX
                     AND    FD.MARCHE = FN.MARCHE
                     AND    FD.NUSEQ IS NOT NULL
                   )
                )
       )
```

*(You can use `IN` rather than `EXISTS` if you prefer.)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=835e25a62a542e7c0e53803fe1b330a5)*

Comment: thanks alot for helping but i as if DISTINCT be reason of degradation performance?

Comment: And i ask if i can more enhance this subquer :.... N.NLBIX IN (
         SELECT /*+ UNNEST NO_USE_HASH_AGGREGATION */
                DISTINCT
                FN.NLBIX
         FROM   DICCRN FN
                LEFT OUTER JOIN RICCRD FD
                ON (   FD.NLBIX  = FN.NLBIX
                   AND FD.MARCHE = FN.MARCHE
                   )
         WHERE  FN.MARCHE IN ('OCC')
         AND    ( FN.NUSEQ IS NOT NULL OR FD.NUSEQ IS NOT NULL )
       )

Comment: The `IN` clause does not care if there is only one or multiple of the same item. If you use `DISTINCT` then the subquery may spend time to filter the list to have no duplicates; run both versions and look at the `EXPLAIN PLAN` and see what the difference is.

Comment: @Ora_as: You should remove `DISTINCT` from any `IN` clause. It just doesn't belong there. The DBMS will decide anyway how to best approach this and may or may not make the values distinct before looking them up. You should also remove the compiler hints (`/*+ ... */`). Usually they are not necessary. Sometimes a flaw in some version makes them necessary, but once you switch versions, you should see whether you can get rid of them again. Hints that once helped improve performance can easily lead to a performance decrease in a newer version.